# Save dynamic data and compare

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I made a code that displays product data in my chat. But if I go to another chat, I will see the same product, because it does not save what it was before. My idea is that when creating a chat, a Thread_id is generated in the URL, it looks like this http://url/bids/#/conversation/73 , where 73 is the thread id. I want it to be assigned to the product data and saved. And when I return to it again, then, accordingly, it will show the desired product, and not what was the last one and is stored in the localStore. How can I implement this?

//This is my code

wp.hooks.addFilter('better_messages_messages_list_before', 'custom_action', function(html, thread) {

```
const lastProduct = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastProduct'));


if (lastProduct) {
    
    html += `<div class="my-custom-product">
                <img class="pr_pimg" src="${lastProduct.image}" alt="${lastProduct.name}" width="100" height="100">
                <div class="pr_name">${lastProduct.name}
                  <div class="pr_price">₽ ${lastProduct.price}</div>
            </div>`;
} else {
    
    html += '<div class="my-custom-product">Продукт <strong>для</strong> торга</div>';
}

return html;
```

});

//This is one of the dozens I have tried.

wp.hooks.addFilter('better_messages_messages_list_before', 'custom_action', function(html, thread) {

```
const currentThreadId = window.location.hash.split('/').pop();


if (isNaN(currentThreadId)) {
    return html;
}


const lastProductData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`lastProductData_${currentThreadId}`));


if (!lastProductData) {
   
    const dynamicProductData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('lastProduct'));

    
    localStorage.setItem(`lastProductData_${currentThreadId}`, JSON.stringify({ thread_id: currentThreadId, product: dynamicProductData }));
}


const updatedLastProductData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(`lastProductData_${currentThreadId}`));


if (updatedLastProductData && updatedLastProductData.thread_id.toString() === currentThreadId) {
    
    html += `<div class="my-custom-product">
                <img class="pr_pimg" src="${updatedLastProductData.product.image}" alt="${updatedLastProductData.product.name}" width="100" height="100">
                <div class="pr_name">${updatedLastProductData.product.name}
                  <div class="pr_price">₽ ${updatedLastProductData.product.price}</div>
            </div>`;
} else {
    
    html += '<div class="my-custom-product">Продукт <strong>для</strong> торга</div>';
}

return html;
```

});